# Javascript: How to reduce json when consecutive key is the same?

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I have a json where I need to reduce the items when they are of a type (`isSender`).
I need to reduce them when they are occurring consecutively.
The data can change.

The data looks like this:

```json
 "messages": [
    { "content": ["Foo"], "isSender": true },
    { "content": ["Bar"], "isSender": true },
    { "content": ["Lorem"], "isSender": true },
    { "content": ["Ipsum"], "isSender": true },
    { "content": ["Dolor"], "isSender": false },
    { "content": ["Sit Amet"], "isSender": false },
    { "content": ["No"], "isSender": true }
  ]
```

I need the content to be an array of messages when the consecutive `isSender` key is the same. The output should look like this:

```json
  "messages": [
    {
      "content": ["Foo", "Bar", "Lorem", "Ipsum"],
      "isSender": true
    },
    { "content": ["Dolor", "Sit amet"], "isSender": false },
    { "content": ["No"], "isSender": true }
  ]
```

So far I have tried looping through the message array and checking if next messages have the same `isSender` key. However this does not work for more than 2 messages.

```
let deleteIndex = [];
 for(let i = 0  ; i < messages.length - 1; i++) {
        const currMs = messages[i];
        const nextMs = messages[i + 1];
        if (nextMs.isSender == currMs.isSender) {
            currMs.content.push(nextMs)
            deleteIndex.push(i + 1) // saving index to be deleted once for loop is done
        }
    }
```

Can someone give me a clue on how to work around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?  I assume you have no problem with JSON.parse or JSON.serialize.  The JSON part of the problem is irrelevant/simple/solved, right?  You are interested in transforming a JavaScript object from the input format to the output format efficiently using economical syntax, right?  You are basically asking for a GroupBy kind of grouping of objects that respects _runs_.  You only want to group consecutive elements.  Kind of like how run length encoding works.  Am I right?

Comment: @Wyck many, many beginners don't understand what JSON is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), on each iteration, we check if the last element in the result array has the same `isSender` value as the current object we're dealing with.

```
if (p.length && p.at(-1).isSender === c.isSender) {
```

So, `if` we already have something in the final array (`p.length`) AND the last `isSender` (`p.at(-1).isSender`) has the same value  as the current `isSender` (`c.isSender`), append to that `content` list

Otherwise, add the entry, which is just the current object itself (`return [ ...p, c ]`)

```js
const data =  [
    { "content": ["Foo"], "isSender": true },
    { "content": ["Bar"], "isSender": true },
    { "content": ["Lorem"], "isSender": true },
    { "content": ["Ipsum"], "isSender": true },
    { "content": ["Dolor"], "isSender": false },
    { "content": ["Sit Amet"], "isSender": false },
    { "content": ["No"], "isSender": true }
  ];
  
const res = data.reduce((p, c) => {
    if (p.length && p.at(-1).isSender === c.isSender) {
        p.at(-1).content.push(...c.content);
        return p;
    }
    return [ ...p, c ];
}, [])

console.log(res);
```

---

Should you not like the `push` way, we can use `Object.assign` to alter the index itself:

```
let i = p.length - 1;
return Object.assign([...p], { [i]: { ...p[i], content: [ ...p[i].content, ...c.content ]}});
```

```js
const data =  [
    { "content": ["Foo"], "isSender": true },
    { "content": ["Bar"], "isSender": true },
    { "content": ["Lorem"], "isSender": true },
    { "content": ["Ipsum"], "isSender": true },
    { "content": ["Dolor"], "isSender": false },
    { "content": ["Sit Amet"], "isSender": false },
    { "content": ["No"], "isSender": true }
  ];
  
const res = data.reduce((p, c) => {
    if (p.length && p.at(-1).isSender === c.isSender) {
        let i = p.length - 1;
        return Object.assign([...p], { [i]: { ...p[i], content: [ ...p[i].content, ...c.content ]}});
    }
    return [ ...p, c ];
}, [])

console.log(res);
```

[Javascript spread on array index to 'push' new item to nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175058/javascript-spread-on-array-index-to-push-new-item-to-nested-array)

---

```json
[
  {
    "content": ["Foo", "Bar", "Lorem", "Ipsum"],
    "isSender": true
  },
  {
    "content": ["Dolor", "Sit Amet"],
    "isSender": false
  },
  {
    "content": ["No"],
    "isSender": true
  }
]
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you do have a typo "were we check".  It could also be that it mutates the original data (the `content` array of some of the original elements gets modified). Just random guesses, though.  I actually think this answer is fine.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter neither, but you can do better than those ugly `.push`-es. No side effects in `.reduce()`, please.

Comment: I choose for push for simplicity. I will change it to a return with spreading the new item in a sec

Comment: @RoboRobok Rather than making the solution horribly inefficient, just don't use `reduce` where a normal loop fits better

Comment: @Bergi the thing is that it doesn't matter when it comes to performance. I mean OP won't run it over millions of entries I suppose. This is where readability is more important. I personally almost never use loops to produce a value.

Answer (score -2):

you can try this

```
var res = {
  messages: [
    { content: [], isSender: true },
    { content: [], isSender: false },
    { content: [], isSender: false }
  ]
};

messages.messages.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.content[0] == "No")  {
res.messages[2].content = ["No"];
res.messages[2].isSender = item.isSender;
  }
  else {
    if (item.isSender)
       res.messages[0].content.push(...item.content);
    else res.messages[1].content.push(...item.content);
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```

json output

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "content": [
        "Foo",
        "Bar",
        "Lorem",
        "Ipsum"
      ],
      "isSender": true
    },
    {
      "content": [
        "Dolor",
        "Sit Amet"
      ],
      "isSender": false
    },
    {
      "content": [
        "No"
      ],
      "isSender": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help! But I need the "No" key to be separate and follow the original order, that is appear after "Sit Amet". Only messages where the previous isSender key is the same (either true or false) should be reduced.

Comment: `JArray`? This is a [tag:js] question, not [tag:c#].

Comment: 35k points and `== true` omg.

Comment: @RoboRobok Thanks,  you found a really big bug (for your big brains)